# ./bin/hbase shell command not working

Tags: hbase, nutch

i am integrating nutch with hbase . While dummy testing hbase . by typing ./bin/hbase shell.... i am getting the following error

./bin/hbase: line 392: /etc/java-7-openjdk//bin/java: No such file or directory

thank you

Comment: Do you have $JAVA_HOME set?

Comment: You should take some time to expand on your question and post some actual code.  Also, like @vastlysuperiorman suggests, it looks like Java might not be in your path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not able to find java at `/etc/java-7-openjdk//bin/java`.  That's where you see `No such file or directory: error`.  Make sure your `JAVA_HOME` is set correctly, jdk is installed and your `hbase` is using `JAVA_HOME` or pointing to the java path which exists.